# FYI - the Stack Exchange iOS app has soft launched

Tags: discussion

Look for an official launch blog post next week if no show stoppers are found, however, you can download the Stack Exchange app now from the App Store.

- [MSE: Was the iOS App Officially Launched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231233/was-the-ios-app-officially-launched)

Get the app - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8

Comment: Why is this announcement posted as a question here? :) Should we all flag this as "unclear what you're asking"? :D

[I thought of posting this as an answer, but realized it might be flagged as "not an answer" and removed :P ]

Comment: Meta has a long standing announcement function, plus the discussion tag is for pure discussion that in any way relates to the site. Is the concept of discussion on meta really unclear to you?

Comment: I don't visit meta regularly like I do the main site. So I wasn't aware of the announcement mode. Nevertheless, the usage of a Q&A format to announce things (where upvotes/downvotes don't really make sense) seems like the right tool is not available/used. The "What's Meta" (http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) page does not mention making community announcements either. And a discussion tag, as that page says, is "for posts that may not have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and are often subjective".

Comment: Tradition and long standing usage aside, I feel that a blog (or a proper bulletin board) would be the right place to post or share announcements and invite comments. In my opinion, announcements would be better shared at http://apple.blogoverflow.com/ (where, incidentally, the last post is dated November 2012).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blog post has all the details. Get some!

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/

Answer (score 1):

Using it now, the only SE client that is superior to just using the mobile web view. Download it! (No offence to the developers of other clients I have beta tested!)

Answer (score 0):

FYI [StackReader](http://stackreaderapp.com/), is currently free ($2 off) on the [App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stackreader/id481243590) right now.